# How to install Python package from specific GitHub HTTPS commit ID

Tags: python, pip

I have a Python package configured like this:

```
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='python-package-test',
    version='0.0.1',
    packages=['python-package-test'],

    dependency_links=[
        # This repo actually exists
        'git+https://github.com/nhooey/tendo.git@increase-version-0.2.9#egg=tendo',
    ],
    install_requires=[
        'tendo',
    ],
)
```

When I install this package from `setup.py`:

```
$ virtualenv --python=python3 .venv && \
    source .venv/bin/activate && \
    python setup.py install

$ pip freeze | grep tendo
tendo==0.2.9  # Note that this is the *correct* version
```

It installs the correct version of `tendo`.

However, when I upload this package in a Git repository and install it with `pip`:

```
# The GitHub link doesn't exist as it's private
# and it's different from the repo mentioned above
virtualenv --python=python3 .venv && \
    source .venv/bin/activate && \
    pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/nhooey/package.git

$ pip freeze | grep tendo
tendo==0.2.8  # Note that this is the *wrong* version
```

It installs the wrong version of `tendo`.

Why is the `setup.py` installation behaving differently from `pip` + `git`?

Answer (score 0):

You must use the `--process-dependency-links` option when installing with Pip, since Pip no longer processes this automatically.

```
pip install --process-dependency-links 'git+ssh://git@github.com/nhooey/package.git'
```

You'd think Pip would print a warning, or the updated version of `setuptools` would also ignore `dependency_links` as well.